# Remove object from NSMutableDictionary at Index

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a `UITableView` that is configured for a subtitle cell.  When I add a cell to the `TableView` I have two arrays.  One for the subtitle and the other for the main label.  I also have an `NSMutableDictionary` so that when I add the cell to the table it records an object and a key.  My problem is when I want to delete the cell from the `UITableView` I use this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [numberArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}
}
```

This works great for removing the objects from their associated arrays, but I also want to remove the objects from the `MutableDictionary` I made.  I thought that you would use somethings  similar to what I used with the arrays.

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But I can't use

```
 [myDictionary removeObjectForKey:indexPath.row];
```

Does anyone know how I would write this?

Comment: There are no indexes in a dictionary.  A dictionary uses keys.

Comment: @HotLicks Means there are *not* indexes in a dictionary.

Comment: What keys do you use when you add an entry to the dictionary?

Comment: @HotLicks, I am sure you meant "There are no indexes in a dictionary".

Comment: As rdelmar suggests, you'd remove using the same key you used to insert the entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `indexPath.row` is a primitive type, it cannot be used as a key in `NSDictionary`: you need to wrap it in `NSNumber` in order to do so.

```
[myDictionary removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
```

This would work only if you use `NSNumber`-wrapped integers as keys in your `NSMutableDictionary`. In general, since `NSDictionary` is an associative container, you need to use the same key in the calls of `removeObjectForKey` as you used in the calls of `setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: Except he hasn't yet said how he's putting the entries *into* the dictionary.

Comment: the subtitle of the cell is the same as the key for the dictionary. If that helps any.

Comment: @Craig your parameter to `removeObjectForKey` needs to match the key you used with `setObject:forKey:`, and it obviously wasn't an integer value, which is what `indexPath.row` is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight @Craig These days you can use literals with clang, e.g. `[myDictionary removeObjectForKey:@(indexPath.row)];`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to delete the data from the NSMutableDictionary

```
//First get all the keys of dictionary into one array
 NSArray *sectionsArray = [mutaleDictionary allKeys];
//Get all the data of tapped section into one array by using indexpath.section
 NSMutableArray *objectsAtSection = [mutaleDictionary valueForKey:[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
//remove the particular object by using indexPath.row from the array
 [objectsAtSection removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```